# duplicating in jsp page,

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I'm facing an duplicating issue with my summary page that's programmed in jsp.

I have three sponsors and each one of them supervises his own school.

When I try to do a select statement for all the important data, and set a condition where the school equals to the sponsor's schoold id, it duplicates all the data three times

here's an image of the duplicating result

[image]

Here is my sql statement:

```
          <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
                SELECT distinct * from Math.Students
                INNER JOIN MATH.Schools
                ON MATH.Students.Schools_idSchools = <%=session.getAttribute("SPONSOR_SchoolID")%>
                INNER JOIN MATH.Sponsor
                ON MATH.Schools.idSchools = MATH.Sponsor.Schools_idSchools
                INNER JOIN MATH.EventPArticipants 
                ON MATH.Students.idStudents = MATH.EventParticipants.Students_idStudents
                INNER JOIN MATH.Events
                ON MATH.EventParticipants.Events_idEvents = MATH.Events.idEvents

              </sql:query>
```

Is there anyway I can avoid the duplicating part ?

Comment: it still prints the result 3 times

Comment: post the jstl `for-each` loop and show us how you are printing it

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
select distinct *
```

on more than one table is silly.  Not only are you going to get the joining fields twice, selecting the unique identifiers guarantees that you will get every row.

Next,

```
from Math.Students
INNER JOIN MATH.Schools
ON MATH.Students.Schools_idSchools = <%=session.getAttribute("SPONSOR_SchoolID")%>
INNER JOIN MATH.Sponsor
```

You are not joining on a field from students equalling a field from schools.  This now becomes a full outer join instead of an inner join.

These two points will improve your results.